# Drupal easy question

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, content-management-system

I'd like to ask how to link to a drupal node?

I've created some page-content but don't know **where** they are and **how** to access them. I'm trying with navigation/menu etc., but still no luck.

Comment: By 'a drupal Page', do you mean a 'node' or a 'menu item' or something else?

Comment: Create content > Page > typing Title and Body > Save - and don't know what to do now? :D

Comment: You're in desperate need for some basic information. Pickup a good tutorial or a book on Drupal fundamentals. Learn the system for a week or so before passing your judgement :-). Drupal 6 interface is not the best in the world but its not so crap as you probably think it is. Drupal did not get to become a top tier CMS just like that :-). Its possible that you're very used to a different CMS paradigm so Drupal isn't making sense to you right now. I personally have come to feel that Drupal offers an extremely logical user interface but then I've been using it for 2+ years.

Comment: This is called a 'node' in Drupal. To access a node, all you need to know is its ID, then you can simply access it through the URL: http://your-site/node/X

Comment: yeah go through some tutorials "Pro Drupal" is a good book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do want to put the pages into the menu system, you can use the "Menu Settings" section of the "create" or "edit" form for the page. Fill in the fields and a link to the page will be added to the menu.

Answer (score 2):

Find it in the content list: `admin/content/node` or try the default node listing for new nodes: `/node`.